# The power set of the intersection of two sets equals the intersection of the power sets of each set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

It would be great if someone could verify this proof.

Theorem:

$\mathcal{P}(A \cap B) = \mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)$

Proof:

First I prove that $\mathcal{P}(A \cap B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)$. Take any subset $X \subseteq A \cap B$. Then $X \in \mathcal{P}(A \cap B)$. Also, $X \subseteq A \wedge X \subseteq B$, meaning that $X \in \mathcal{P}(A) \wedge X \in \mathcal{P}(B)$. This, again, means that $X \in \mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)$, and this proves the statement.

Then I prove that $\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A \cap B)$. Again,  take any subset $X \subseteq A \cap B$. Using just the same arguments as above, this is also a truth.

The theorem follows.

Comment: The first part is fine, the second one is less than lousy and I'd personally would grade it with a beautiful and round zero. Be formal as you were in the first part and show what you must, and while doing it realize that it is **not** the same arguments you have to use as before.

Comment: Yes, I see this now. I must learn to think clearer. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Nice, wise and relevant answer, @Tullball: way to go. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Again,  take any subset $X \subseteq A \cap B$."*

You might want to change the wording here. "Take any set $X$ such that $X \subseteq A$ and $X \subseteq B$. Then $X \subseteq A \cap B$."

As written it sounds like you're assuming what you want to prove. Otherwise good...

Comment: Oh! Yes! I realize this now. I think I understand "both directions" now. So this is very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

For the first half, you want to prove that any member of $\mathcal{P}(A \cap B)$ is a member of  $\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)$. So the proof should *start* "Suppose $X \in \mathcal{P}(A \cap  B)$". Then you *derive* $X \subseteq A \cap B$, and the rest goes as you state. (Except, don't use "means" for "implies".)

For the second half, you aren't going to use "just the same arguments" or you'd end up showing that $\mathcal{P}(A \cap B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A \cap B)$ which isn't what you meant!

Comment: Yeah, I see that one must start with precisely the same as the thing one assume. Thanks! I'm learning. :-)

Answer (score 2):

$
\newcommand{pow}[1]{\mathcal P(#1)}
$For comparison, here is another way to prove this: start with the most complex side, investigate which elements are in that set by expanding the definitions, and then try to simplify.  So we calculate, for any $\;V\;$,
\begin{align}
& V \in \pow A \cap \pow B \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\cap\;$"} \\
& V \in \pow A \;\land\; V \in \pow B \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\pow{\quad}\;$, twice"} \\
& V \subseteq A \;\land V \subseteq B \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"set theory: property of $\;\cap\;$"} \\
& V \subseteq A \cap B \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\pow{\quad}\;$"} \\
& V \in \pow{A \cap B} \\
\end{align}
By set extensionality, this proves $\;\pow A \cap \pow B \;=\; \pow{A \cap B}\;$.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking to prove a similar statement, but about an arbitrary intersection. This example seemed a good foundation to base the more general proof:

Let $\textbf{X}$ be a nonempty collection of sets. Prove that 
$\mathcal{P}(\bigcap \textbf{X}) = \bigcap \{\mathcal{P}(A) \mid A \in \textbf{X} \}$.

**Proof**. Let $\textbf{X} = \{X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{n-1}, X_n\}$ be a nonempty 
collection of sets and let $x \in \mathcal{P}(\bigcap \textbf{X})$. Then
 
      
$\begin{aligned}
    x \in \mathcal{P}(\bigcap \textbf{X}) &\iff x \in \mathcal{P}(X_1 \cap X_2 \cap \dots \cap X_{n-1} \cap X_n) \\
    &\iff x \subseteq (X_1 \cap X_2 \cap \dots \cap X_{n-1} \cap X_n) \\
    &\iff x \subseteq X_1 \wedge x \subseteq X_2 \wedge \dots \wedge x \subseteq X_{n-1} \wedge x \subseteq X_n \\
    &\iff x \in \mathcal{P}(X_1) \wedge x \in \mathcal{P}(X_2) \wedge \dots \wedge x \in \mathcal{P}(X_{n-1}) \wedge x \in \mathcal{P}(X_n) \\
    &\iff x \in \mathcal{P}(X_1) \cap \mathcal{P}(X_2) \cap \dots \cap \mathcal{P}(X_{n-1}) \cap \mathcal{P}(X_n) \\
    &\iff x \in \bigcap \{\mathcal{P}(A) \mid A \in \textbf{X} \}.
    \end{aligned}$
 
Since $x$ was an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{P}(\bigcap \textbf{X})$, we have shown that
${\forall x \big( x \in \mathcal{P}(\bigcap \textbf{X}) \iff x \in \bigcap \{\mathcal{P}(A) \mid A \in \textbf{X} \} \big)}$, 
or $\mathcal{P}(\bigcap \textbf{X}) = \bigcap \{\mathcal{P}(A) \mid A \in \textbf{X} \}$. $\square$
 
 
However, the follow-up problem leaves me with a question. I mechanically changed intersections to unions and **and**s to **or**s from the proof above, but I don't know how to incorporate the condition "if
and only if $\bigcup \textbf{X} \in \textbf{X}$". I believe one of the steps below does not actually hold unless I use this condition, and I think it's step three, but I'm not sure of the justification:
 
Let $\textbf{X}$ be a nonempty collection of sets. Prove that 
$\mathcal{P}(\bigcup \textbf{X}) = \bigcup \{\mathcal{P}(A) \mid A \in \textbf{X} \}$ if
and only if $\bigcup \textbf{X} \in \textbf{X}$.
 
**Proof**. Let $\textbf{X} = \{X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{n-1}, X_n\}$ be a nonempty 
collection of sets and let $x \in \mathcal{P}(\bigcup \textbf{X})$. Then
 
      
$\begin{aligned}
    x \in \mathcal{P}(\bigcup \textbf{X}) &\iff x \in \mathcal{P}(X_1 \cup X_2 \cup \dots \cup X_{n-1} \cup X_n) \\
    &\iff x \subseteq (X_1 \cup X_2 \cup \dots \cup X_{n-1} \cup X_n) \\
    &\iff x \subseteq X_1 \vee x \subseteq X_2 \vee \dots \vee x \subseteq X_{n-1} \vee x \subseteq X_n \\
    &\iff x \in \mathcal{P}(X_1) \vee x \in \mathcal{P}(X_2) \vee \dots \vee x \in \mathcal{P}(X_{n-1}) \vee x \in \mathcal{P}(X_n) \\
    &\iff x \in \mathcal{P}(X_1) \cup \mathcal{P}(X_2) \cup \dots \cup \mathcal{P}(X_{n-1}) \cup \mathcal{P}(X_n) \\
    &\iff x \in \bigcup \{\mathcal{P}(A) \mid A \in \textbf{X} \}.
    \end{aligned}$
 
Since $x$ was an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{P}(\bigcup \textbf{X})$, we have shown that
${\forall x \big( x \in \mathcal{P}(\bigcup \textbf{X}) \iff x \in \bigcup \{\mathcal{P}(A) \mid A \in \textbf{X} \} \big)}$, 
or $\mathcal{P}(\bigcup \textbf{X}) = \bigcup \{\mathcal{P}(A) \mid A \in \textbf{X} \}$.
$\square$

Answer (score 1):

In the fullest generality, consider a nonempty set $I$ and a family $A$ of sets indexed by $I$ (such that we will write $A_i$ for the set corresponding to index $i \in I$).

We then have:
$$X \in \bigcap_{i \in I} \mathscr{P}(A_i) \Longleftrightarrow (\forall i)(i \in I \Rightarrow X \subseteq A_i) \Longleftrightarrow X \subseteq \bigcap_{i \in I} A_i \Longleftrightarrow X \in \mathscr{P}\left(\bigcap_{i \in I}A_i\right)$$

and the equality
$$\bigcap_{i \in I}\mathscr{P}(A_i)=\mathscr{P}\left(\bigcap_{i \in I}A_i\right)$$
follows from the axiom of extensionality.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountred this question while studying for a test, here's what i got:
Text book answer:
$X∈P(A∩B) \Leftrightarrow X⊆A∩B \Leftrightarrow X⊆A \ and \ X⊆B \Leftrightarrow X∈P(A) \ and \ X∈P(B) \Leftrightarrow X∈P(A)∩P(B)$

Hope it serves you well :)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please typeset your formulas using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks @csch2 glad to contribute and learn