# Proving $\mathscr P(A)\cap\mathscr P(B)=\mathscr P(A\cap B)$ is my proof valid?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Prove that $\mathscr P(A)\cap\mathscr P(B)=\mathscr P(A\cap B)$.

Consider the set $X=\{x\}$ with $X\in\mathscr P(A)\cap\mathscr P(B)$. This means that $X\in\mathscr P(A)$ and $X\in\mathscr P(B)$ and so $x\in A$ and $x\in B$.Then by the definition of intersection $x\in(A\cap B)$. But then by the definition of the powerset, we have $X\in\mathscr P(A\cap B)$ which means $\mathscr P(A)\cap\mathscr P(B)\subseteq\mathscr P(A\cap B)$.

Now consider the set $Y=\{y\}$ where $Y\in\mathscr P(A\cap B)$. Then we have $y\in A\cap B$. THis means $y\in A$ and $y\in B$. Therefore we must have $Y\in\mathscr P(A)$ and $Y\in\mathscr P(B)$ and so by the definition of intersection we have $Y\in\mathscr P(A)\cap\mathscr P(B)$ and thus $\mathscr P(A\cap B)\subseteq\mathscr P(A)\cap\mathscr P(B)$.

By the above arguments we can see that $\mathscr P(A)\cap\mathscr P(B)=\mathscr P(A\cap B)$.

$\blacksquare$

My concern is that this proof is invalid because I followed the exact same argument in part 2 as in part 1 but in reverse. Is this a problem or does my proof work? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you only considering single element sets $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: You have only proven the statement for singletons $\{x\}$. But what happens for other, more general sets? See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490524/the-power-set-of-the-intersection-of-two-sets-equals-the-intersection-of-the-pow) for a similar question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is invalid because you've only shown the sets you claim are equal contain the same singletons. You should use the general observation$$\begin{align}X\in\mathscr{P}(A)\cap\mathscr{P}(B)&\iff X\in\mathscr{P}(A)\land X\in\mathscr{P}(B)\\&\iff X\subseteq A\land X\subseteq B\\&\iff\forall x\in X(x\in A)\land\forall x\in X(x\in B)\\&\iff\forall x\in X(x\in A\cap B)\\&\iff X\subseteq A\cap B\\&\iff X\in\mathscr{P}(A\cap B).\end{align}$$