# Prove that: $P(A) \bigcap P(B) = P(A\bigcap B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> How to prove: $$P(A) \bigcap P(B) = P(A\bigcap B)$$

I got that this is true by taking values and checking.

Ex:

$ A = {\{1.2\}}$

$P(A)= {\{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}}$

$ B = {\{2,3\}}$

$P(B)= {\{\emptyset, \{2\},\{3\},\{2,3\}\}}$

So,
$$P(A) \bigcap P(B)= {\{\emptyset,\{2\}\}}=P(A\bigcap B)$$

But how to prove it in general?

Any ideas or hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The power set of the intersection of two sets equals the intersection of the power sets of each set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490524/the-power-set-of-the-intersection-of-two-sets-equals-the-intersection-of-the-pow)

Comment: "I got that this is true by taking values and checking." Then it's true for those values. We are not allowed to say the statement is true based on just a few trials.

Comment: @Kaira I went through the reference link and over there Eric Auld has said: "Take any set $X$ such that $X \subseteq A$ and $X \subseteq B$. Then $X \subseteq A \cap B$." But how is that a proof? Alvin Lepik just told that we're not allowed to claim the statement true if it's true for some values. I didn't get the explanations there. Also Scott Weitzenhoffer has given a really tough explanation and I didn't get that. I would be grateful if this question doesn't pass off as a duplicate, because I still haven't got it.

Also SolubleFish, thanks for your edit.

Comment: Do you see that if $X$ were such that $X\subseteq A$ and $X\subseteq B$ that it would be that $X\in \mathcal{P}(A)\cap \mathcal{P}(B)$ and vice versa?  This is by definition.  Do you see that if $X$ were such that $X\subseteq A\cap B$ that $X\in \mathcal{P}(A\cap B)$?  This too is by definition.  Now... about the only thing left that should cause issue is showing that $X\subseteq A$ and $X\subseteq B$ together are equivalent to $X\subseteq A\cap B$.

Comment: "*The elements of $X$ are all elements of $A$ and the elements of $X$ are all elements of $B$*" compared to "*The elements of $X$ are all elements of $A$ and elements of $B$*"

Comment: @Crease Let's say we want to prove $x+x=2x$ for all $x$. we can easily calculate that $1+1=2$ and $2+2=4$. Do these two statements prove that $x+x=2x$ for all $x$? No, because we didn't prove it for all $x$. He pointed out that, by "taking values and checking", you only proved the statement for those special $A$ and $B$ and not the general case.

Comment: @Crease Also did you see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/734236/691829) answer in the same question? This looked very clear to me.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I have understood it now yay

Comment: @Crease Your argument may not depend on the choice of $A$ and  $B$. But it does if you let $A$ and $B$ be something specific as in your initial attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, note that
$$
P(A) = \{X:X\subseteq A\}\text{ and }P(B) = \{X:X\subseteq B\}
$$
then
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(A)\cap P(B) & = & \{X:X\subseteq A\} \cap \{X:X\subseteq B\}\\
              & = & \{X:(X\subseteq A)\wedge(X\subseteq B)\}\\
              & = & \{X:X\subseteq A\cap B\}\\
              & = & P(A\cap B)
\end{eqnarray*}

The important one is the handling of the intersection and the associated logical operator. This property can be verified for any set of indexes $I$, then

\begin{equation*}
P\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i}\right) = \bigcap_{i\in I}P(A_{i})
\end{equation*}